# Is the point of the Gelfand triple/Hilbert triple that we don't need to write as many symbols?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $V \subset H$ be a continuous embedding of Hilbert spaces. Let $I\colon V \to H$ be the inclusion map. Let $R\colon H \to H^*$ be the Riesz map. Then we have for $h \in H$ and all $v \in V$
$$\langle I^*Rf, v \rangle_{V^*,V} = (f,v)_H$$
where $I^*\colon H^* \to V^*$ is the adjoint map of $I$.

Now let us identify $H$ with its dual and make $V \subset H \subset V^*$ a Gelfand triple. In this case, we would write for any $h \in H$ and $w \in V$ the formula
$$\langle h, w \rangle_{V^*,V} = (h,w)_H.$$

So is the whole point of the Gelfand triple that it means we don't need to write $I^*R$ in the first displayed equation? It is just a notation?

Comment: Having seen various undergraduate (and a few graduate) books on quantum mechanics, I suspect that the notion of the Gelfand triple / [rigged Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) was introduced because physicists had been using [Dirac notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) but pretending that $V = H = V^{*}$. Many good ideas for physics had arisen without rigor, and the Gelfand triple helped put this on firmer ground while preserving some notation.

Comment: I think the "usual" Gelfand triple is $\mathcal S(\Bbb R^n)\to H \to \mathcal S^*(\Bbb R^n)$, here $\mathcal S$ is the space of Schwartz functions which is a Frechet space, not a Hilbert space. As JoeMack remarks this allows you to give rigorous meaning to the "bra"s $\langle x|$ and $\langle p|$. The formal connection of this $\langle x|$ with "$|x\rangle \langle x|$", which is the projection valued measure associated to the operator $x$, is still somewhat mysterious to me.

Answer (score 5):

In [*Quantum Mechanics Beyond Hilbert Space*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2780592_Quantum_Mechanics_beyond_Hilbert_space), [Jean-Pierre Antoine](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jean-Pierre_Antoine) explained that  the rigged Hilbert space formalism gives quantum theorists access to **generalized eigenvectors** of ([extensions](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Extension_of_an_operator) of) linear operators that have continuous spectrum. These generalized eigenvectors can be used to represent a variety of operations in a more familiar setting and notation.

In particular, if the rigged Hilbert space is $\Phi\subset\mathcal{H}\subset\Phi^{\times}$, then each self-adjoint operator on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ has an [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators) that has a complete orthonormal set of generalized eigenvectors in $\Phi^{\times}$, and inner products of vectors in $\Phi$ can be expressed as integrals with respect to a (conventional?) measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I should note that Antoine assumed that $\Phi^{\times}$ consists of [*antilinear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map) functionals on $\Phi$ that are continous with respect to a topology with respect to which $\Phi$ is complete.

Comment: I think there are more things to be said about the extension of operators than you hint at. For example you need $\Phi$ to be an invariant subspace of the domain of the operator and the restriction of the operator to $\Phi$ should be continuous and the operator to be closed. I believe the dual operator then agrees with the Hilbert space adjoint on $H$. The Wikipedia link you give discusses a different kind of extension problem, which is "more classical" (ie older).

Comment: @s-harp: You are correct; my links may mislead some readers, particularly in this case. There are specific requirements that $\Phi$ must satisfy in Antoine's essay. $\Phi$ must be nuclear as well as complete with respect to a topology finer than the norm topology of $\mathcal{H}$. This allows the use of the Gelfand-Maurin nuclear spectral theorem, which, I must admit, is beyond my experience in this area.

Comment: I'm not familiar with most of the stuff around this either, but that is a very nice introduction,  very clear and almost conversational.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's good to know the history of it but I'm more talking about the actual practical implications of it in terms of the question

Comment: @stopusingfacebook: The direct answer your question is _No_. The property you described in your question is not the only benefit of the rigged Hilbert space formalism. The primary benefit, as J.-P. Antoine saw it, is the availability of generalized eigenvectors, which can be manipulated in almost the same way as vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ but can be used to represent a wide variety of useful operations.